# Formatting the float numbers in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

When the mouse moves to the series, highcharts displays all the numbers, as shown in this picture:

[image]

I want to make the float numbers all have 2 digits after dot point. I searched online, and came up sth like:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + ' %';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dataLabels controls numbers that show up near the points on the chart itself.  That rollover you have in your image is the tooltip.  Check out:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/valuedecimals/

```
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
formatter: function () {
    let perc = this.percentage.toFixed(2)
    return `<span>${perc}%</span>`
}
```